# Can someone explain why is my code giving error "floating point exception"

Tags: c

I was trying to solve a problem but i was getting some error i debugged but cannot find can someone find it.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

long long int fact(int n)
{
  long long int s=1,i;

  if(n==0||n==1)
    return(1);
  else {
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      s=s*i;
    }

    // printf("%lld ",s);
    return(s);
  }  
}

int comb(int m,int n)
{
  float data;  
  data=fact(m+n)/(fact(m)*fact(n));

  // printf("%d %d data:%d ",m,n,data);
  return(data);
}    

int main() { 
  float nu[100];
  int t,i,n,a,b,w,j,k,l,c[100];

  scanf("%d",&t);    
  for(j=0;j<t;j++) {
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
      a=i,b=n-i;
      w=comb(a,b);
      nu[i]=w;
      c[i]=i;
    }

    for(k=0 ;k< i;k++) {
      for(l=0;l<i-1;l++) {
        if(nu[l]>nu[l+1]) {
          int p,q;

          p=nu[l];
          nu[l]=nu[l+1];
          nu[l+1]=p;
          q=c[l];
          c[l]=c[l+1];
          c[l+1]=q;
        }

        if(nu[l]==nu[l+1]) {
          int q;

          if(c[l]>c[l+1]) {
            q=c[l];
            c[l]=c[l+1];
            c[l+1]=q;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for(l=0 ; l < i ;l++) {
      //printf("%d",nu[i]);
      printf("%d ",c[l]);
      printf("%d\n",n-c[l]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because of division by zero.. Maybe here:`data=fact(m+n)/(fact(m)*fact(n));`

Comment: Since `fact(0)` returns 1, this seems not to be the case...

Comment: The largest factorial that fits into a `long long int` is `20!`. And any `n >= 66` will return `0` from the `fact` function.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a better algorithms for `comb()` that won't have problems for values as low as 20. You can derive this by cancelling the values of the division so you only multiply together the values that you need.

Comment: @user3386109 For large `n`, `fact()` may return anything, including 0, as integer overflow (`s=s*i`) is not defined.

Comment: @identicon Provide sample inputs that code give exception.

Comment: "floating point exception” may be a response due to an _integer_ division by `0`.  Wherever code does an integer division like `data=fact(m+n)/(fact(m)*fact(n));`, precede it with a zero check to narrow the scope of this problem.  @Cool Guy is likely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comb() returns "int" type, but you "return(data);", which is "float" type:

```
int comb(int m,int n)
{   
  float data;  
  data=fact(m+n)/(fact(m)*fact(n));
  // printf("%d %d data:%d ",m,n,data);
  return(data);
 }
```

Comment: Same comes for int also